# Redirect links on github

Tags: protege

I am trying to put redirect links on Protege IRI. I am trying to do the same as this tutorial explains. I am trying many hours/days to make this work. https://linkingresearch.wordpress.com/2016/01/17/permanent-identifiers-and-vocabulary-publication-purl-org-and-w3id/ Ok, I have understand what I do with the github links. But what should I do with the redirect links on IRI on Protege? What I do with them? Where do I put them on the .htaccess file?? Somewhere else?

Comment: In step 6 it says: "Wait until the admins accept your changes." This means when  I get "All checks have passed" + "This branch has no conflicts with the base branch" messages  on my github so I close the pull request? Do I get any other message from the admin of the w3id.org on my github account? How do I find out that the admin accepted the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the tutorial seem straightforward to me.

You start with an ontology file and a place in the web that you control, e.g., the URL of your GitHub repository. Call the URL `U` and the ontology file `F`.

Your ontology file contains an ontology, which you wish to have a stable URL no matter where it's hosted. So, `F` can be downloaded at `U` but you do not wish people to have to know `U`, you want them to know `https://w3id.org/PATH/NAME` as a nice, abstract way to refer to your ontology. So, the content of `F` says that the ontology IRI is `https://w3id.org/PATH/NAME`

You fork the project in order to be able t create a pull request; in the forked repository, you create the folder `PATH` (ensuring it's a path that does not already exist). You place an `.htaccess` file in the folder `PATH`.

In the `.htaccess` file you add a rewrite rule for `NAME` (I know nothing f HTTP rewrite rules, I'm just reading the example file) and enter `U` - so that a browser will attempt to connect to `https://w3id.org/PATH/NAME`, and this portion `https://w3id.org/PATH/` will let the browser find the `.htaccess` file.

Here the rewrite rule will be applied and `https://w3id.org/PATH/NAME` will change to `U`, and then the content of `F` will be downloaded.

You need the administrator to accept your pull request for `https://w3id.org/PATH/NAME` to work; if that does not happen, then the URL in your fork would still do the job - and you can use this as an experiment to make sure your `.htaccess` is working as you wish it to. E.g., my fork is at `https://github.com/ignazio1977/w3id.org`, so I could use `https://github.com/ignazio1977/w3id.org/PATH/NAME` to redirect to `U`.